# Exposed view filter is not rendered properly

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a view with a filter "Has taxonomy term", this filter is an exposed filter and is set to be a "Dropdown" and "Show Hierarchy"

The vocabulary has parents and children term (hierarchical).

The filter works fine but the html tags of the select dropdown are incorrect. The parent terms should be wrapped in  instead of  (see image 2)

Can I override this?

[image]

I trying to do it with **hook_form_alter()** but I see that the construction of the select itself is done by **drupal_map_assoc()** function. Then I see no way to do it? Can I put the value for '#options' in other way?

```
<?php
  $form['undergraduate']['school_country'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array(t('UK'), t('Other'))),
    '#title' => t('In what country is your college or university located?'),
  );
?>
```

Comment: This is how it is meant to look/work. It does not provide <optgroup> functionality. I had to do this once and did it with custom code in a form_alter

Comment: ok, I just need that the user can't select a parent item, and indent to the right a little bit the children items. I will try to use form alter

Comment: You could check if it is the top level (maybe by checking if it doesn't have a - at the start), and then add the attribute disabled (disabled="disabled")

Comment: You could also use this module: http://drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree. It has on option to only allow selection of the lowest term in the hierarchy. I used it on a site recently and it worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if it is the top level (maybe by checking if it doesn't have a - at the start), and then add the attribute disabled (disabled="disabled")

You could also use this module: drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree. It has on option to only allow selection of the lowest term in the hierarchy. I used it on a site recently and it worked well.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know the term_reference_tree module.